# How to create timer in swift using (NStimer)

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to make countdown (NSTimer).

for example:- count down timer 2d:21h:50m:20s

I used some code:-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
 self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.UpdateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        }
    
@objc func UpdateTime() {
   let userCalendar = Calendar.current
    // Set Current Date
   let date = Date()
   let components = userCalendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .month, .year, .day, .second], from: date)
   let currentDate = userCalendar.date(from: components)!
        
   // Set Event Date
        var eventDateComponents = DateComponents()
        eventDateComponents.year = 2020
        eventDateComponents.month = 07
        eventDateComponents.day = 2
        eventDateComponents.hour = 0
        eventDateComponents.minute = 0
        eventDateComponents.second = 0
        eventDateComponents.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
        
        // Convert eventDateComponents to the user's calendar
        let eventDate = userCalendar.date(from: eventDateComponents)!
        
        // Change the seconds to days, hours, minutes and seconds
       let timeLeft = userCalendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDate, to: eventDate)
        
                // Display Countdown
       timerLabel.text = "\(timeLeft.day!)d \(timeLeft.hour!)h \(timeLeft.minute!)m \          (timeLeft.second!)s"
                // Show diffrent text when the event has passed
            }
```

My API Response:-

```
func callForTimerApi(){
     
        let url = "\(ApiLink.HOST_URL)/wp/v2/getDeadline"
      
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    print(value)
                    let dict = value as! [String:Any]
                    
                    let userData = dict.validatedValue("data", expected:[[String:Any]]() as AnyObject) as! [[String:Any]]
                    
                  
                  for item in userData {
                      let length = item.validatedValue("length", expected: String() as AnyObject) as! String
                      print(length)
                    self.counters = Int(length)!
         
                  }
                    
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                presentAlert("", msgStr: "Could not connect to the server.", controller: self)
                
            }
        }
        
    }
```

I got it 48 length in hours from API,and my coutdown timer starts 2d:24h:45m:20s and my starts timer is over than show countdown timer is 0d:0h:0m:[image]0s

Comment: Sorry, but i don't get the question. The timer doesn't fire?

Comment: I agree, it's not clear what you are trying to do and there is no real question asked so you really need to make this question clearer and explain your issue properly.